# How to find the character index of an XPath match with libxml2?

Tags: c, xml, xpath, libxml2

Given an XML file (stored in, say, `sample.xml`), and an XPath expression (say, `//storyinfo`), I want to get the character index in the XML file of the start of each node that results from evaluating the XPath expression.

A line number and a column number would also be fine.

**What I've tried:**

Given a sample XML like this one, stored in `sample.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<story>
  <storyinfo>
    <author>John Fleck</author>
    <datewritten>June 2, 2002</datewritten>
    <keyword>example keyword</keyword>
  </storyinfo>
  <body>
    <headline>This is the headline</headline>
    <para>This is the body text.</para>
  </body>
</story>
```

I can get the "storyinfo" node using an XPath expression with libxml2, like so:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <libxml/parser.h>
#include <libxml/tree.h>
#include <libxml/xpath.h>

int
main(void)
{
    int i, size;
    char *filename;
    xmlChar *xpath_expr;
    xmlDocPtr doc;
    xmlNodePtr node;
    xmlNodeSetPtr nodes;
    xmlXPathContextPtr xpath_ctx;
    xmlXPathObjectPtr xpath_obj;

    /* Read file. */
    filename = "sample.xml";
    doc = xmlParseFile(filename);
    if (doc == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: unable to parse file \"%s\"\n",
            filename);
        exit(1);
    }

    /* Evaluate XPath expression. */
    xpath_ctx = xmlXPathNewContext(doc);
    if (xpath_ctx == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: unable to create new XPath context\n");
        xmlFreeDoc(doc);
        exit(1);
    }
    xpath_expr = (xmlChar *)"//storyinfo";
    xpath_obj = xmlXPathEvalExpression(xpath_expr, xpath_ctx);
    if (xpath_obj == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr,
            "Error: unable to evaluate XPath expression \"%s\"\n",
            xpath_expr);
        xmlXPathFreeContext(xpath_ctx);
        xmlFreeDoc(doc);
        exit(1);
    }

    /* Print XPath matches. */
    nodes = xpath_obj->nodesetval;
    size = (nodes) ? nodes->nodeNr : 0;
    for (i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        node = nodes->nodeTab[i];
        printf("Match %d - Name: %s\n", i, node->name);
        printf("Match %d - Content: %s\n", i, node->content);
        printf("Match %d - Line: %d\n", i, node->line);
        printf("Match %d - Extra: %d\n", i, node->extra);
    }

    /* Cleanup. */
    xmlXPathFreeObject(xpath_obj);
    xmlXPathFreeContext(xpath_ctx);
    xmlFreeDoc(doc);

    return 0;
}
```

Here I saw that in libxml2, the node has a field `line`, with a value of `3`, which is the line number in which the node is located in the XML file. However, that is not helpful if the XML is all in a single line (which isn't uncommon).

What I want instead is the character index: in the `sample.xml` above, that would be `50`. Either that, or a line and column number: in the example above, that would be line `3`, column `3`.

Comment: I suspect you'll find that libxml2 does not retain this information. Any extra information held with every node gets very expensive when you're dealing with gigabyte files.

Comment: The source https://github.com/GNOME/libxml2/blob/master/include/libxml/tree.h#L490 suggests there is only line information, no column information stored.